# How to add new custom dynamic link in magento2 top header links?

Tags: magento2, customer-account, customer-group, toplinks, magento2.3.0

I want to add a custom dynamic link on top gray navigation bar besides welcome message when a specific user with a specific customer group is logged in.
the main entry would be dynamic which will contain a changing numeric value via ajax.
and then under it will come menu items with independant dynamic links.
Similar to My account, My wishlist, Signout menu. but dynamic.
In short I need to get what is shown below:

[image]

Please guide where to start from.

I have searched but till now found only for mein menu custom links for cms etc.
I need in top grey section.

Comment: have you check this https://belvg.com/blog/creating-dynamic-links-in-my-account-or-in-the-toplinks-menu-in-magento.html if not. I will add it in the answer it will surely help you in creating dynamic link ?

Comment: I have seen this blog, but this is not helping me in adding the popup/handle the html below the link. Also the fact that its using `customer_account_navigation` which will create link on the left menu, if I am not wrong.

Comment: Also its of magento1